# Matrix Determinant with trigonometry part 2

Tags: matrices, determinant

**How can the determinant of this matrix**

$$\left(%
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \sin (a)    & \cos(a) & 1  \\
 \sin(b)     & \cos(b) & 1 \\
  \sin(c) &  \cos(c)        & 1  \\
\end{array}%
\right)$$

May be $\sin(a-b)-\sin(a-c)+\sin(b-c)$

This is what i got so far:
$$\sin(a)\cos(b)\cdot1+\cos(a)\cdot1\cdot\sin(c)+1\cdot\sin(b)\cos(c)-\sin(c)\cos(b)\cdot1-\cos(c)\cdot1\cdot\sin(a)-
1\cdot\sin(b)\cos(a)$$ but I cannot seem to go any further. Any help?

Comment: First term and last term in your expansion is the first term in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sin(a-b) = \sin a\cos b-\sin b\cos a$.

Answer (score 1):

If you subtract the first row from the second and the third, the determinant doesn't change, so you determinant is the same as
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}
\sin a & \cos a & 1 \\
\sin b-\sin a & \cos b-\cos a & 0 \\
\sin c-\sin a & \cos c-\cos a & 0
\end{pmatrix}=
\det\begin{pmatrix}
\sin b-\sin a & \cos b-\cos a \\
\sin c-\sin a & \cos c-\cos a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This becomes
\begin{align}
&\color{red}{\sin b\cos c}-\color{green}{\cos a\sin b}-\color{blue}{\sin a\cos c}+\sin a\cos a \\
&\qquad-\color{red}{\cos b\sin c}+\color{green}{\sin a\cos b}+\color{blue}{\cos a\sin c}-\sin a\cos a\\
&=\color{red}{\sin(b-c)}-\color{blue}{\sin(a-c)}+\color{green}{\sin(a-b)}\\
&=\sin(a-b)+\sin(b-c)+\sin(c-a)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the matrix in question $A$. You have arrived at
$$\begin{align}\det(A)=&\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(c)+\sin(b)\cos(c)-\sin(c)\cos(b)-\cos(c)\sin(a)-\\&-\sin(b)\cos(a)\end{align}$$
now you can use the identity $\sin(x-y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)-\sin(y)\cos(x)$ for any $x,y\in\Bbb R$. Rearranging the above determinant, we have:
$$\begin{align}\det(A)=&\left(\sin(a)\cos(b)-\sin(b)\cos(a)\right)+\left(\sin(b)\cos(c)-\sin(c)\cos(b)\right)-\\&-\left(\sin(a)\cos(c)-\sin(c)\cos(a)\right)\end{align}$$
the result follows from this.